# How to substitute placeholders in word documents w/o office installed?

Tags: .net, ms-office

It might be acceptable to use rtf and just rename extension to doc/docx/whatever.

Comment: Would this be in `.doc` or `.docx`? The latter gives more options but might have compatibility issues depending on target users.

Comment: @Richard I'll clarify that tomorrow (hopefully). Tips for both will do. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very simple solution without using .net. A docx file is just a bunch of xml files zipped together.  So

1. unzip file.docx
2. replace placeholder in `word/document.xml` (or all xml files if the placeholder can be anywhere, like footnotes, etc.)
3. zip them together, again with docx extension

Comment: Useful info. That's that office openxml thingy, right? Must talk with client first though. Don't know atm if they need support for regular .doc too.

Comment: Btw, it worked marvelously. Could spit out filled documents like from a machine gun. Ty for idea. Only bad thing was that word enjoyed screwing up my templates. Here's how I fought that: http://vimeo.com/28398983 :)